# Identify iOS view controller type

Tags: ios

Can't think what to call this type of view controller/UIView. It's the "new/replied" part of my screenshot which is from the standard Apple calendar app on iOS7.

Screenshot: http://cl.ly/XIbb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a `UITableViewController` that has a `UISegmentedController` as the navigation bar's `titleView`. That's the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the navigation item with a segmented control. See the titleView property of the navigation item: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView